# Detecting iPhone camera orientation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, camera, uiimage

I'm getting inconsistent results depending on whether I get the image directly from the camera in the callback or choosing it from the camera roll.

In the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` callback method, the `UIImage.imageOrientation` comes up as `UIImageOrientationRight` no matter how the photo is taken.

When reading it off the Camera Roll, a landscape shot (turned left) comes up `UIImageOrientationUp` while a portrait shot comes up `UIImageOrientationRight`.

How can I reliably get the camera orientation in both situations?

Comment: I found this somewhat related link http://mohrt.blogspot.com/2009/05/camera-image-orientation.html and am aware of the scaleAndRotateImage code http://blog.logichigh.com/2008/06/05/uiimage-fix/

... but neither explain why I might be getting incorrect imageOrientation information directly off of the image passed in from the callback.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. For instance imageOrientation is 3(UIImageOrientationRight,90 deg CW, according to apple docs) when I have the iphone in the upright position and it's 0(UIImageOrientationUp) when it's turned left(should be UIImageOrientationRight I believe). Have you found any solution?

Comment: I haven't found a solution, but I've been meaning to check of OS 3.0 fixes this.

Comment: Add me to those afflicted: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/69393?tstart=0

Comment: It is also worth noting that the behavior is different on different devices (iPod vs iPhone4) and os versions 4.0, 4.1, etc.  On our App we had to special case a bunch of combinations to get full coverage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted this to the Apple forums, and got the explanation:

"The camera is actually landscape native, so you get up or down when you take a picture in landscape and left or right when you take a picture in portrait (depending on how you hold the device)."

See:

```
https://devforums.apple.com/message/301160#301160
```

Thanks:

https://devforums.apple.com/people/Rincewind

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the imageOrientation property after the picture has been taken, it's funny because I have the orientation values messed up. Up is Left, Down is Right, Left is Down and Right is Up, for example, if I hold the iPhone "Up" (the normal position) then imageOrientation is "UIImageOrientationRight".

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
  didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
      editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {
    switch (image.imageOrientation) {
      case UIImageOrientationUp: //Left
       break;
      case UIImageOrientationDown: //Right
       break;
      case UIImageOrientationLeft: //Down
       break;
      case UIImageOrientationRight: //Up
       break;
      default:
       break;
     }
}
```

Currently I am using 4.1 SDK GM (xcode_3.2.4_and_ios_sdk_4.1_gm_seed) targeting for iOS 3.1

Comment: Have you had any joy just hacking that conversion?

Answer (score -1):

I have read [somewhere](http://joris.kluivers.nl/iphone-dev/?p=IncorrectlyRotated) that the UIImagePickerController doesn't turn on listening to hardware orientation events, so you may need to call

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

before you capture images in your own app.  I'm about to go try testing this myself, so I hope it works!

Comment: Actually the syntax you meant is: [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];