# Saving UIImages to files without using NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsdata

I want to store a bunch of images that are taken while the user uses the app, while making sure that I can view them with decently high resolution later on. And by "store", for now I don't need to store them past the closure of the app. Simply having them available after some point while the app is still alive is all I need.

I first tried simply storing the UIImages in their original size on the app, but then the app would crash after 7 or 8 pics were taken because of memory usage.

I then tried shrinking them (since my app has a grid display wherein I can see all the pictures, but shrunk to fit on a 3x3 grid of images) , and my app stopped crashing. But when I wanted the pictures to be viewed individually on full screen, the quality was terrible because I was enlarging a shrunk photo.

So I figured why not find a way to store the original image through another object in a way that wouldn't eat up too much memory. Searching online lead me to decide to store them in a file, by converting the images into NSData and then writing this into a file. BUT, when I would then load the NSData back into a UIImage, the orientation of my photos taken through the camera were all sideways! And after hours of looking (and failing) through  how to transform it back into the proper orientation, I've decided to give up on trying to fix this orientation bug.

Instead, I just want to know if there is any other way for me to store large/high-res UIImages  (without hogging up memory) besides using NSData. What ideas do you guys have?

*And pardon me for having to write so much for a one-liner question. I just didn't want to get suggestions on doing something I've already tried.*

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14553866/updating-uiimage-orientation-metadata

Comment: Thanks. This helped, I simply set the orientation to be UIOrientation...Right whenever I get an image from the camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save it as a jpeg instead of a PNG, that way the image will be rotated for you.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4868914/96683

Comment: Thanks, while I did solve my issue using the method I stated above in the comments, I can think of some edge cases wherein my method stated above might cause errors. In the case that I have to deal with those edge cases, I will come back to this and implement what you just suggested.

Comment: What edge cases are those?